# Setting a document in the Google Firestore database

Tags: c#, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I seem to be having a problem with setting a document in the Google Firestore database in Visual Studio. I am following the guide provided by Google on their website (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). I am no expert in C# and I do not know what does this mean.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("dzapp1-a2bfd");
        Console.WriteLine("Created Cloud Firestore client with project ID: {0}", "dzapp1-a2bfd");
        Console.ReadKey();
        DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("cities").Document("LA");
        Dictionary<string, object> city = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "name", "Los Angeles" },
            { "state", "CA" },
            { "country", "USA" }
        };
        WriteResult writeResult = await docRef.SetAsync(city);
        Console.WriteLine(writeResult.UpdateTime);
    }
}
```

}

The program seems to be having a problem with this line:

```
WriteResult writeResult = await docRef.SetAsync(city);
```

It says that the 'await' operator could only be used within an async method.
As I said, I am no expert in C# and I am helpless, does anyone have an idea how to rewrite the code so everything works? I tried googling the async method and putting the code in it, but where do I go from there? How do I call the method? (if thats what you do with it). Thanks for every answer guys, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably readed, you should use await in a method which is marked with the async modifier.
Take a closer look at the complete source code for that example will clarify how the await is used in an async method:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/ffd0e648acbcfe26500f9247e54c10b15f10079e/firestore/api/AddData/Program.cs#L45-L53

Specifically: Look at the AddDocAsMap's signature and how it is called from Main

Comment: Thank you so much man, I really appreciate it. I feel ashamed that I haven't found this yet and that I had to bother you, thank you very much. I am glad you are here to help newbies like me :) Thank you once again.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you found this useful. Every one of us is a newbie in a lot of subjects ;)